# Must use mockbean instead of autowired

Tags: spring-boot, junit

I use spring boot 2

I created a basic test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class VehicleServiceImplTest {

    private VehiculeServiceImpl service;

    @Autowired
    private VehicleRepository repository;

    @Before
    public void prepare() {
        service = new VehiculeServiceImpl(repository);
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){

    }

}
```

I get

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'com.namur.service.VehicleServiceImplTest': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through field 'repository';  nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'com.namur.repository.VehicleRepository' 
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:586)

If i replace Autowired by MockBean it's working but I don't know why

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> If i replace Autowired by MockBean it's working but I don't know why

It works because `@MockBean` replaces or **adds** a bean **into** the Spring context.
In your case, it adds a `repository` mock in the Spring context.
So this could not throw any `UnsatisfiedDependencyException`.

But that is not necessary what you need as you used initially `@Autowired` that is designed to inject a bean **from** the context.

`@Autowired` and `@MockBean` are indeed two very different things that you never substitute for a same need.

---

As a side note, you should probably rethink the way which your test is built.

Actually you are using the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` runner.
It means that you want to use the Spring container for your test.
It is a valid approach. But in this case, why do you create VehiculeServiceImpl outside the Spring container ?

```
 service = new VehiculeServiceImpl(repository);
```

You should rather inject the service.

Note that creating a new instance of the class under test outside the containers is also a very valid approach.
We do it as we write plain unit tests. If you want to do it, don't use the Spring Boot runner, that by the way, makes tests slower.

Comment: My service take a repository in parameter

Comment: It doesn't matter. You can inject it in your test in this way :  `@Autowired
    private VehicleService service;`. You have just ensure you correctly the the application context in the test class declaration. Annotate the class with `@SpringBootTest` may do it.

Answer (score 13):

It is because you have not supplied the test with any indication of what the spring context is hence there are no beans at all available to autowire.

By providing a `@MockBean` you are essentially providing a test context with a single existing bean which is a mock of the `VehicleRepository` class.

You can use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation which will load a spring context for you to use in your test. Then you should be able to `@Autowired` the actual repository:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class VehicleServiceImplTest {
```

Comment: Based on the title for this question this should be the accepted answer.. brief and right to the point..