# SpringBootTest fails due to UnsatisfiedDependencyException during Jenkins build with Docker

Tags: java, docker, maven, jenkins, spring-boot-test

First of all, it might look duplicate to other post on stackoverflow, and I tried couple of solutions. But, none solving my issue.

**Issue :**

Springboot test getting failed due to UnsatisfiedDependencyException during jenkins build. But, interestingly, on local system I don't see same exception and I'm able to build same codebase without any error/exception.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'myAppServiceImpl' defined in file [/use/jenkins/path
> to class/MyAppServiceImpl.class] : Unsatisfied dependency expressed through
> constructor parameter 1;

I'm getting this issue only during jenkins build whereas on my local system. I'm able to build the same codebase without any issue. So, I'm not sure what should I make change to make it work on platform.

Due to restriction, I won't be able to share exact code, but I'm sharing similar to it.

```
package com.tg.app.main.engine

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MyApplicationProperties.class)
@ComponentScan("com.tg.app")
class MyApplication{
// main method
}
```

**Test**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes=MyApplication.class)
@AutoConfigurationMockMvc
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient(timeout="100000")
class MyApplicationTest{

 @Autowire
 private MyAppService myAppService;

//codes

}
```

**Service**

```
   package com.tg.app.main.engine.service
   public interface MyAppService{
   //method declaration
   }

   @Service
   public MyAppServiceImpl implements MyAppService{
   private UserService userService
   private String xyz;

      @Autowire
      public MyAppServiceImpl(String xyz, UserService userService){
       this.xyz=xyz;
       this.userService=userService;
      }
   }
```

I also tried adding `MyAppService` as below as suggested in some post.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes={MyApplication.class, MyAppService.class})
```

Then, one of the post on stackoverflow ([Must use mockbean instead of autowired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48503613/must-use-mockbean-instead-of-autowired)) suggesting not to use `@MockBean` (Although, I tried it, which didn't helped in my case). So, I'm not sure what should I do to fix this issue. Need help. Since, this is only occurring on platform, so not possible to hit and trail there multiple times.

Please let me know, if any other information is required.

**==Edit==**

The same code was earlier working fine. This time we have upgraded the SpringBoot version from `2.0` to `2.1` and removed couple of unnecessary libraries. As mentioned above, code is just to give you an idea about the structure of code. They aren't actual code. Another thing to note here is, ***I'm able to successfully build same code on local machine and even bring up the service without any issue***. So, I'm very sure, nothing wrong with the code. It's something to do with platform where this code is getting built.

I noted couple of differences between my local machine and platform. First, build triggered using `Docker`, which isn't the case when I'm doing in local (just executing maven command). And other one is, Integration Testing running using `OpenJDK` (`maven 3.3.9-jdk-8`) on platform whereas on my local I'm using `Java Hotspot (Oracle jdk-8)`. Other than this, I didn't see any difference between local system and platform.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share the pom.xml or gradle file

Comment: @VipulJain as mentioned, due to code restriction, I'm unable to share. So, I have to type entire pom to share here. Let me know, if you need anything specific from the pom. I can share specific portion.

Comment: can you add the code for your `UserService`? And what `String` do you expect to inject? Is this some `@Value("${myProperty}")` or who/what populates this?

Comment: @rieckpil I have updated my post. Please refer my edit.

Comment: The problem has to do with the `UserService` parameter, for any reason Spring could not inject a bean of that type when constructing `MyAppServiceImpl`. Is it possible that in your local machine you have some library or some version of the library, in your maven repository, different than the one accessible to the maven build? Maybe the build process is fetching an old or different artifact. Does the stack trace provide more information about the problem? Perhaps the error is a consequence of any other problem that it causing the `UserService` bean to be unavailable.

Comment: @jccampanero As mentioned, the same code was getting build successfully on the platform earlier. Now, since you mentioned about library, to confirm, I actually deleted all jar from `.m2` folder. Then, triggered maven again on my local machine. But, I was still able to build on my local machine. On platform, it starts `docker` first and then execute `mvn clean package`. I can check with platform team, if they could ensure cleaning up existing library before triggering the build.

Comment: @jccampanero Referring stacktrace, I have updated it in my post, and that's it. Nothing much we get from it. I suspect, something to do with platform, may be because platform using `OpenJDK` whereas in my local `Java Hotspot` or may be docker is blocking something on the platform. Since, I don't have much knowledge about `docker`. I couldn't talk about it. Or may be `Springboot 2.1`

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @cool_ravi. Please, be aware that the post was not updated for any reason with the stack trace information. I see. If you have control over the pipeline, you can force snapshot updates (I do not if it can be relevant or not in your case) running maven like this: `mvn -U clean package`. Please, also pay attention to the existence of any maven profile. In addition, is `UserService` accessing to any resource that it is not available from Jenkins? I mean, a database, a LDAP service,... Does it use any `Class.forName` or dynamic class loading mechanism? See next comment

Comment: Again, maybe the problem could be related with the creation of the `UserService` bean. I hope any of the mentioned approaches help.

Comment: @jccampanero I don't have control to run any command on the platform. But, will try to reach out to the team. But, I suspect something to do with platform rather code issue otherwise I should get same issue on local machine.

Comment: I understand @cool_ravi. I hope they can provide you some insights into the problem. Any way, I think it would be great if you could expand the stack trace of the error in your question to include the root cause, I think it will be of help in the resolution of the problem.

Comment: Your `UserService` is not in context during test (`Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1;`). What package is it in? Does it have it's own dependencies? To confirm, temporarily add `@MockBean UserService userService` in your test. As noted by others, without full stack trace we can only guess what is the problem.

Comment: I had faced a similar issue with maven build in Jenkins. The issue was with the order in which the beans were created. To fix the issue, I made one of the core dependent bean 'Primary'. This required some hit and trial and multiple commits for Logging on the availability of beans when the objects was initiated.

Comment: Have you installed OpenJDK (maven 3.3.9-jdk-8)) locally so that testing locally in the same environment ? If you do that, just change the PATH with new java configs and in you ide, point to the right maven and jdk.

Comment: yes, I tried it and there was no difference. I'm also struggling to find any documentation or sample code to enable `wiremock` server logging.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your String `xyz` in `MyAppServiceImpl`, Spring isn't actually finding an autowire candidate, you could add to your test class:

```
@MockBean
private String xyz = "whatever you are trying to inject";
```

This way you will surpass your failed dependency injection

Comment: Pls note, as I have already mentioned same code is working in local. So, I don't think there is any issue with code anyway. I'm suspecting issue with platform configuration or some library conflicts. I'm anyway debugging it on platform with hit and trail.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at code that is not currently causing the issue is a wast of time.

If you can`t share the actual code due to confidentiality, then you should create a test project that gives you the same error and share here.

That been said, I advise you to check for any profiles in maven that are active in your machine, but is disabled in the jenkins environment, or vice versa.